# MySQL: compare two database

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to compare two database? assuming I have same schema, and by compare, I mean I need to know if data value's are the same. I need to do that within MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just to compare - use [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) from [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html).

you'll find there also other tools - eg. [mk-table-sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) that you can use to sync back one server to another in an efficient way.

Comment: my tables are mix between MyISAM and InnoDB